# Adding a new root node to a existing treeview's parent node

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I selected the parent node (the top) in treeview. and now i need to add a new parent node to the existing parent node dynamicly. 
here is my way of solving to the problem:
`

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text.Trim());
//here comes an error of null reference argument

//To avoid that error,i tried it in this way:
   if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent == null)
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent=new TreeNode(textBox1.Text.Trim());
```

`
But it still returns an error. Help me solve this.
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Trying this wont work:

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text.Trim());
```

Since you are trying to find the Parent of the top node who doesn't have a top node.

To add a new top node you need to add it to the list of top nodes:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text.Trim());
```